# iOS 9 UIWebview black bar increasing on frame change

Tags: uiwebview, ios9

I am facing an issue related to UIWebview on iOS 9. When i try to change the frame for UIWebview by changing its height constraint through UIPangesture, It adds black area at the bottom of webview. This area goes on increasing as i scroll. Can anyone help?